# Upgrade JDK1.5 to 1.8 on EA Server 5.5

Tags: java-8, java-5, easerver

I'm using EAServer 5.5 on Windows7 and the server is running with JDK 1.5

Now I want to UpGrade JDK1.5 to 1.8. Can you please some one help me.

I am getting the following error.

```
DynamicLibrary::lookup: af_dll_lookup (libjjdk12.dll, new_JagComponent) failed (libjdispatch) (Y:\calm\conn\itg\jagsrv\generic\dispatch\DynamicLibrary.cc@80)
000095 Tue Jul 21 12:50:32 2015 E [018286] CTS_JagComponent::load:  failed to load component model library (libjdispatch) (Y:\calm\conn\itg\jagsrv\generic\dispatch\CTS_JagComponent.cc@841)
000096 Tue Jul 21 12:50:32 2015 E [018918] CTS_Component::load: failed for component 'Jaguar/Repository' (libjdispatch) (Y:\calm\conn\itg\jagsrv\generic\dispatch\CTS_Component.cc@1993)
000097 Tue Jul 21 12:50:32 2015 A [099999] SystemException: OBJECT_NOT_EXIST (CosNaming/NamingContext/resolve - @0.0.0.0) (libjdispatch) (Y:\calm\conn\itg\jagsrv\generic\dispatch\CTS_Object.cc@3995)
000098 Tue Jul 21 12:50:32 2015 E [018532] Exception 'CORBA::OBJECT_NOT_EXIST' in Session::create for component 'Jaguar/Repository' (libjdispatch) (Y:\calm\conn\itg\jagsrv\generic\dispatch\Session.cc@1029)
000099 Tue Jul 21 12:50:32 2015 A [099999] SystemException: OBJECT_NOT_EXIST (Session/create - @0.0.0.0) (libjdispatch) (Y:\calm\conn\itg\jagsrv\generic\dispatch\CTS_Object.cc@3995)
000100 Tue Jul 21 12:50:32 2015 A [099999] new_JagObjectRef: Bad URL - Jaguar/Repository (libjdispatch.iiop) (Y:\calm\conn\itg\jagsrv\generic\cc\JagORB.c@1074)
000101 Tue Jul 21 12:50:32 2015 E [018480] SEVERE ERROR - failed to access Jaguar Repository (libjdispatch.repository) (Y:\calm\conn\itg\jagsrv\generic\dispatch\Repository.cc@114)
000102 Tue Jul 21 12:50:32 2015 E [018488] Warning: failed to lookup properties for Package'CosNaming'(CORBA::INV_OBJREF) (libjdispatch.repository) (Y:\calm\conn\itg\jagsrv\generic\dispatch\Repository.cc@187)
000103 Tue Jul 21 12:50:32 2015 E [018477] Missing value for Component 'CosNaming/NamingContext' property 'com.sybase.jaguar.component.type' (sybase.eas.global) (Y:\calm\conn\itg\jagsrv\generic\dispatch\Properties.cc@151)
000104 Tue Jul 21 12:50:32 2015 E [018918] CTS_Component::load: failed for component 'CosNaming/NamingContext' (libjdispatch) (Y:\calm\conn\itg\jagsrv\generic\dispatch\CTS_Component.cc@1993)
000105 Tue Jul 21 12:50:32 2015 A [099999] SystemException: OBJECT_NOT_EXIST (CosNaming/NamingContext/resolve - @0.0.0.0) (libjdispatch) (Y:\calm\conn\itg\jagsrv\generic\dispatch\CTS_Object.cc@3995)
000106 Tue Jul 21 12:50:32 2015 E [018532] Exception 'CORBA::OBJECT_NOT_EXIST' in Session::create for component 'Jaguar/JavaInit' (libjdispatch) (Y:\calm\conn\itg\jagsrv\generic\dispatch\Session.cc@1029)
000107 Tue Jul 21 12:50:32 2015 A [099999] SystemException: OBJECT_NOT_EXIST (Session/create - @0.0.0.0) (libjdispatch) (Y:\calm\conn\itg\jagsrv\generic\dispatch\CTS_Object.cc@3995)
000108 Tue Jul 21 12:50:32 2015 A [099999] new_JagObjectRef: Bad URL - Jaguar/JavaInit (libjdispatch.iiop) (Y:\calm\conn\itg\jagsrv\generic\cc\JagORB.c@1074)
000109 Tue Jul 21 12:50:32 2015 F [018506] SEVERE ERROR - failed to access Jaguar/JavaInit (libjdispatch) (Y:\calm\conn\itg\jagsrv\generic\dispatch\Server.cc@418)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible or recommended.

OP was asking for upgrading Java (inside) used by EAServer (app server like JBoss, but for PowerBuilder+Java). Most of the Java classes inside EAServer were compiled to Java 1.2 and support only up to Java 1.5. I recently tried to upgrade my EAS 5.5 to JDK 1.6. This caused above issues you mentioned. 
Several things are at play here:

1. Deprecated Java classes, methods, models.
2. JDBC interface itself is different now. For Oracle, I had to use OJBC6 and that breaks with older databases.

In the end, decided to simply upgrade JDK to 1.5.0_22, max build for 1.5 (Sybase's own limit was 1.5.0_03).

That said, if you still want to try, you will have to update a few batch files (I am assuming you are on windows) in \bin.

- You may have to install/copy the JDK inside Sybase\Shared
  folder, so you can customize, if needed.
- You will need to add new JDK entries into setenv.bat and
  serverstart.bat. Basically, current batches are agnostic about the
  new JDK versions you are introducing to the EAServer.

  - You may have to update user_setenv.bat to customize JDBC/classpaths.
- You may also have to generate batch file for Jaguar Manager and
  change Java directory used to launch it.

It didn't work for me. But, if you are able to make it to work, can you please post back with your suggestions here?

Comment: Thanks for reply sam.

I have tried same and i am not able to start service once changes done.

I am getting the Error:1067 The process terminated unexpectedly.              please share if any other thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply. Been busy with a project. Are you still having the problem? That essentially says the service did not start. Did you look at the Jaguar.log?

I suggest, you start it using the batch file first -
 \EAServer\bin\serverstart.bat -jdk18

I hope you have added jdk18 options in the batch files. And watch the below logs:

Jaguarout.log, Jaguar_performance.log (if found), Jaguar.log

Once you get it to work, then you can use Serverstart with -install option to start as a service.

I just want to reiterate, that even if you get it to start, you may have issues with connection caches (particularly JDBC) and other interfaces as the specifications changed a lot since Java 1.4. If you are getting issues there, you will have to update the OJDBC driver etc. Good luck!